# Cocoapods post_install, how to add target membership in Pods project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-project, xcodeproj

I have a Podfile, that when constructing the Pods.xcodeProj ends up with an included xcframework that is a Pods.xcodeproj file reference, that I need to add as a target reference to one of the pods built targets.

I think it's possible to do such a thing in the Podfile `post_install` phase, but I cannot figure out the `xcodeproj` gem syntax required to (A) find the Nami.xcframework reference I need to add to the target, then (B) add that file reference to the desired target (see image below for the framework I wish to adjust target membership for, I basically just want to automate checking that target membership box).

My start to this Podfile script looks like:

```
post_install do |installer|
    nami_target = installer.pods_project.targets { |f| f.name == "react-native-nami-sdk" }

    #Pseudocode begins here, this is what I cannot figure out
    nami_xcframework_fileref = ??
    nami_target.addBuildReference(nami_xcframework)
end
```

Thanks for any help on this, I've found a number of example pod file scripts but none seem to do quite what I am trying to do.

[image: Screen shot showing framework and target membership I need to adjust in Podfile]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure out the full script I needed, the Podfile post_install script below does exactly what I was looking for.

Note that a key was that while you can examine targets by using the `.name` property, for file references only `.path` will always have contents you can examine, `.name` is often blank.  Also another key item, is that you need to add the file reference to the `frameworks_build_phase` aspect of the target.

The final script (added to the end of a Podfile):

```
post_install do |installer|
  puts("Attempting to add Nami.xcframework reference to react-native-nami-sdk project.")
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name  == "react-native-nami-sdk"
      puts("Found react-native-nami-sdk target.")
      all_filerefs = installer.pods_project.files
      all_filerefs.each do |fileref|
         if fileref.path.end_with? "Nami.xcframework"
          puts("Found Nami.xcframework fileref.")
          build_phase = target.frameworks_build_phase
          puts("Determining if react-native-nami-sdk build phase needs correction.")
          unless build_phase.files_references.include?(fileref)
            puts("Adding Nami.xcframework to react-native-nami-sdk target")
            build_phase.add_file_reference(fileref)
          end
         end
      end
    end
  end
end
```